# Old Space movie about 1980-1999

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

Please help to find this space movie, I remembered I watching this on video but I was quite scared so I only saw some of it!

The story happens on a spaceship en-route to another planet. There are about 8 people in team that were sent to another planet. But all people are in sleep capsules. When it's time to awaken they find the captain dead in mysterious circumstances.

The last surviving crew-member is a female android. Her head gets cut off and placed into a box(?).  I stopped watching after that...

Comment: Did they all get killed off one-by-one? Who was doing the killing? Was the last surviving crew member a woman or an android?

Comment: Not placing in the box but on the box only head of woman who has bold hair. there are many current connect to her head which on the box.

Comment: Wow.  "Old" movie.  From the 80's. Sigh.  I need a drink.

Comment: @Paul not sure in exactly year but I watched this in the VDO when I was 8 year old (just about for 19 years)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like ["Star Quest" (1994)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114533/?ref_=nv_sr_2)

Here's the trailer link:

[Star Quest Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gv-mh2cy5nQ)

It's been awhile since I last seen it. But I remember it starts with the mysterious death of their Captain and turns out to be a female android and took apart her head. Everything is in the trailer, good luck.

Answer (score 11):

"Jason X"(2001)?

It has a female android whose head gets knocked off by Jason, and it does have 8 main players in the beginning of the movie. Of course, it's a Friday the 13th movie, so it isn't long before Jason whittles them down to two survivors. Here is part of the plot synopsis from Wikipedia:

> The survivors set explosive charges to separate the remaining pontoon from the main drive section. As they work, Jason is accidentally brought back to life by the damaged medical station, rebuilt as an even more powerful cyborg called Uber Jason. Jason easily defeats KM-14 by punching her head off. As Tsunaron picks up her still-functioning head, Jason attacks them but is stopped by Waylander, who sacrifices himself by setting off the charges while the others escape. Jason survives and is blown back onto the shuttle. He punches a hole through the hull, blowing out Janessa. A power failure with the docking door forces Brodski to go EVA to fix it.

Here is a trailer. You can see Kay Em 14, the female android, right before her battle with Jason at 1:15:00.

Comment: thank you but it is not. It just like America send the crew (about 8-9 people in team) for find something.. however, this story starts that all people sleep in capsule for timing to get up. Only captain die in the capsule in mystery. So they find someone who kill captain...